# "Place was called on a node which was placed already"

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I've upgraded Jetpack Compose from 1.1.0-beta03 to 1.1.0-beta04, nothing happened except some change to do, but now i have this error when i'm launching the app on a "DetailScreen".

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.antigaspi, PID: 6067
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Place was called on a node which was placed already
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode.onNodePlaced$ui_release(LayoutNode.kt:941)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.InnerPlaceable.placeAt-f8xVGno(InnerPlaceable.kt:125)
    at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable.access$placeAt-f8xVGno(Placeable.kt:31)
    at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable$PlacementScope.placeRelative(Placeable.kt:359)
    at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable$PlacementScope.placeRelative$default(Placeable.kt:179)
    at androidx.compose.foundation.layout.PaddingModifier$measure$1.invoke(Padding.kt:370)
    at androidx.compose.foundation.layout.PaddingModifier$measure$1.invoke(Padding.kt:368)
    at androidx.compose.ui.layout.MeasureScope$layout$1.placeChildren(MeasureScope.kt:68)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.placeAt-f8xVGno(DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.kt:126)
    at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable.access$placeAt-f8xVGno(Placeable.kt:31)
    at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable$PlacementScope.place-70tqf50(Placeable.kt:370)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.OuterMeasurablePlaceable.placeOuterWrapper-f8xVGno(OuterMeasurablePlaceable.kt:171)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.OuterMeasurablePlaceable.access$placeOuterWrapper-f8xVGno(OuterMeasurablePlaceable.kt:28)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a [known issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/208855077) with Compose 1.1.0-beta04 that is already fixed for the next version of Compose. Unfortunately, there isn't any workaround until that next version is available.

Comment: Erf... Thank you, i was not able to find a topic about this on google.
I can't progress on my project, it happened 100% of the time now, don't know why, mayeb because of ModalBottomSheet

Answer (score 1):

It is fixed in Compose 1.1.0-rc01 which is available now.